# viewWillAppear isn't called as expected

Tags: ios

In my application, the data in the input fields across my views change constantly, so each time a view is brought onto the screen I need to run a function to sort what's displayed.

I found -(void)viewWillAppear, but this isn't being called when I press the "back" button which fires off my segue back from my NavController for some reason. I've read a few threads on this and it seems to me it's a bit ambiguous how it works internally.

How can I force a function to fire every time a view is brought on screen?

The code is basically as simple as

.h

```
@interface view1 : UIViewController
```

.m

```
// ... do stuff in viewDidLoad
//     I added below, but the code never runs through it.
-(void)viewDidAppear
{
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: where have u implemented -(void)viewWillAppear i.e. in the UIView class or UIViewcontroller class?

Comment: @Ishank It's in the .m file of a view which is from UIViewController

Comment: check if the view is set as the view of the UIViewController..

Comment: Noob question. How can I be sure? Everything is generic without much customization in my app.

Comment: your OS is below ios5.0?

Comment: Every thing else works properly? You might want to add some code!

Comment: Code to my question, or?

Comment: Yes ..@JesseMeyer, please add some code to you question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method signature is wrong - the correct method is:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

You don't get any error as you can always define your own method, and its not like this is in a protocol.